# Catch exception in JS

Tags: javascript

I've got next code that fills page with data I get from server every 10 sec:

```
var refreshFunction = function() {
        //get data from server
        $.get("<c:out value="${baseURL}"/>/js/getCounts", function(data) {
            vardata = data;
        });

        if (vardata != null) {
            //divide
            countArray = vardata.split("/");
            //if server returns "-" or new array with new structure
            if ((vardata == "-" || length != countArray.length)
                    && !(document.getElementById('requestForm') instanceof Object)) {
                //reload
                location.reload();
                clearInterval(refreshId);
            } else {

                //fill page with data
                for (var j = 0; j <= countArray.length; j++) {
                    console.log(countArray[j]);
                    $('#badge_' + (j + 1)).text(countArray[j]);
                }

            }
        }

    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        refreshId = setInterval(refreshFunction, 10000);
    });
```

The code works, but if I open application and then turn off my server, script will never stop. I'm having

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

How can I catch it and stop the script after that? I was trying to wrap code blocks with `try` and `catch(e)`, but doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the AJAX request is executed asynchronously, wrapping your code in `try ... catch` will not catch the exception. The exception happens *after* your code has finished executing.

You should handle the `.fail` case on the object returned by [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to avoid seeing that error reported on the console:

```
 var jqxhr = $.get("<c:out value="${baseURL}"/>/js/getCounts", function() {
    vardata = data;
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

---

As a side note, you should put the complete body of your function inside the call back in `$.get`. Otherwise, you'll always be running your code with the *old* dataset, not the new one.

This problem doesn't show up in your code in the first execution because `vardata` is probably `undefined` and in Javascript land, `undefined != null` is `false`.